# C# Assign values to a SOAP envelope using a dictionary?

Tags: c#, soap

I feel like this is probably a pretty basic question, but I'm new to SOAP its associated namespaces, etc so here goes:

I have a SOAP request that looks something like (full request abridged for brevity):

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:addLine sequence="?">
     <line>
        <pattern></pattern>
        <description></description>
        <usage></usage>
        <routePartitionName uuid="?"></routePartitionName>
        <callForwardAll>
              <forwardToVoiceMail></forwardToVoiceMail>
           <callingSearchSpaceName uuid="?"></callingSearchSpaceName>
           <secondaryCallingSearchSpaceName uuid="?"></secondaryCallingSearchSpaceName>
              <destination></destination>
        </callForwardAll>
        <callForwardBusy>
              <forwardToVoiceMail></forwardToVoiceMail>
           <callingSearchSpaceName uuid="?"></callingSearchSpaceName>
              <destination></destination>
        </callForwardBusy>
        <callForwardBusyInt>
              <forwardToVoiceMail></forwardToVoiceMail>
           <callingSearchSpaceName uuid="?"></callingSearchSpaceName>
              <destination></destination>
        </callForwardBusyInt>
```

The values for these elements are going to be pulled from a combination of app.config and things the user has input on the form and I figured a dictionary would be the most straight-forward way of assigning the values to the elements.

So here's my question; how do I assign values to the "forwardToVoiceMail" and "secondaryCallingSearchSpaceName" elements when they each could have different values?  I mean, the dictionary only has two dimensions, the key and the value, so I can't have `callForwardAll\forwardToVoiceMail, true` and `callForwardBusy\forwardToVoiceMail, false` in the dictionary.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

XML like a hierachical data structure seems cumbersome to me to relate it to a Dictionary, as you mention it. Another way is that you creates classes that resemble your XML layout. So yo create:

```
` public class ClassForward
     bool ForwardToVoiceMail;
     GUID callingSearchSpaceName;
     GUID secondaryCallingSearchSpaceName;
     string Destination;
  end;

  public class Line
    string pattern;
    string description;
    ClassForward callForwardAll;
    ClassForward callForwardBusy;
    ClassForward callForwardBusyInt;
    ...
 `
```

Then save and read using XmlTextWriter and XmlTextReader  in memory using something like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, new XmlWriterSettings()));
SaveLines(ref writer, Lines);
```

Where :

```
public void SaveLines(ref XmlTextWriter writer, List<Line> myLines)
{
    foreach(Line line in MyLines)
    {
       writer.WriteStartElement("line");
       writer.Add(new XElement("pattern", line.pattern));
       writer.Add(new XElement("description", line.description));
       writert.Add(new XElement("CallForwardAll", 
                   new XElement("forwardToVoiceMail", line.forwardToVoiceMail));
```

...
        }

You get the idea.

Comment: Or you could just decorate the classes with the appropriate attributes and just use XmlSerializer instead of the custom xml generation you are doing.